# flutter_facebook_auth error at try generate archive xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, facebook-login, flutter-facebook-login

I'm having an error with the `flutter_facebook_auth` plugin when trying to generate an Archive in Xcode.

When I run the application in debug mode, the app does not show any errors related to the plugin. However, when trying to generate an Archive to upload to the AppleStore, the xcode reports some errors, as follows:
[image: Erro aparece quando tento gerar um Archive]

my flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.2, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-x64, locale en-BR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.64.0)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

I've looked at some related forums in search of a possible solution, but I haven't found it.

NOTE: Some of my attempts were

- enter the Podfile and uncomment the line #platform :ios, '9.0' for version '10.0'
- i did run the commands `pod repo update`, `pod install` and other commands that cause the pod to be restructured from a modification I have made.